# Image displays fine in IE while colors are messed up in Chrome/FF

Tags: .net, image, browser, cross-browser

This is one of the cross browser quirks that just makes one laugh.

Compare this in IE and Chrome/FF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VwNJ.jpg

Notice how in Chrome/FF the color palette is almost inverted to what is shown in IE.

Has anyone experienced this? The image was rescaled with a custom built .net image resizer. I'm not the programmer but just trying to find out if anyones seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JPEG image has a device-specific color profile https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl6Fm.png assigned to it. If used on the web, a standard color profile such as *sRGB* should be assigned instead. On Windows, color profiles in JPEG files are parsed and used in Chrome and Firefox according to the current monitor profile. In contrast, IE (as far as I know up to IE9) just ignores the monitor's color profile and uses a standard *sRGB* profile instead. This is mentioned online, for instance, http://help.fotopedia.com/entries/22366773-Color-management-beware-of-IE9.

You can convert your original JPEG files to use a standard *sRGB* profile. The color should then be correct. For example, a converted file is viewable here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvuI8.jpg